# Variable is null, but im never even creating it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im currently getting this error repeatedly even after removing all mentions of the left variable from the code
[image: Picture of the website]
This happened after i tried to add a background to one of my div elements, i removed the code for the background but the error persisted, i then tried removing all code expect the html and the error still persisted, i did check to see if the files were saved

Also, the animation works as intended, and it wouldn't work if left was actually null

Full code (App.js is the same):
Header.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Header = () => {
    const left = document.getElementById("left-side");
    const right = document.getElementById("right-side");

    let isLeftVisible = true;

    const switchSides = () => {
        isLeftVisible = !isLeftVisible;

        if (isLeftVisible) {
            left.style.width = "0%";
        } else {
            left.style.width = "100%";
        }
    }

    // Set the initial timer
    let timer = setInterval(switchSides, 3000);

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(switchSides, 3000);
    });

    document.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(switchSides, 3000);
    });

    // Apply smooth transition using CSS transitions
    left.style.transition = "width 1.5s";
    right.style.transition = "width 1.5s";

    return (
        <>
            <div id="left-side" class="side">
                <h2 class="title">
                    Sometimes a simple header is 
                    <span class="fancy">better</span>      
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="right-side" class="side">
                <h2 class="title">
                    Sometimes a simple header is  
                    <span class="fancy">worse</span>     
                </h2>
            </div>

            <a id="source-link" class="meta-link" href="https://superlist.com" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i>
                <span class="roboto-mono">Source</span>
            </a>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Code with only html:

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';

const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Header = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <div id="left-side" class="side">
                <h2 class="title">
                    Sometimes a simple header is 
                    <span class="fancy">better</span>      
                </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="right-side" class="side">
                <h2 class="title">
                    Sometimes a simple header is  
                    <span class="fancy">worse</span>     
                </h2>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: It's because you're trying to access the left and right elements before they are rendered in the DOM.

Comment: There's quite a lot of signs of fundamental misunderstandings of React here. You shouldn't be accessing DOM nodes via `getElementById` and you definitely shouldn't be trying to call `addEventListener` here or mutate `style`. I would suggest going through https://react.dev/learn. Currently, it looks like you wrote vanilla js inside of a react component without actually using React constructs to achieve your goals.

Comment: I was trying to add normal js because i had the code and i wanted to incorporate this into my react project, but why is the error still there after removing the code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was trying to use vanilla js and i seems to try to get the elements before they are rendered, so i tried doing the logic from scratch in a more "react" way.

Header.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Header = () => {
    const [leftSideWidth, setLeftSideWidth] = useState('100%');

    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        // Toggle between 100% and 0% width
        setLeftSideWidth((prevWidth) => (prevWidth === '100%' ? '0%' : '100%'));
        },6500);

        return () => {
        // Cleanup interval when component is unmounted
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        };
    }, []); // Empty dependency array to run the effect only once on component mount
    
        return (
        <>
            <div id="left-side" className="side bg-blue-300 transition-all duration-[1500ms]" style={{ width: leftSideWidth }}>
                <h2 className="title">
                    Sometimes a simple header is
                    <span className="fancy">better</span>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="right-side" className="side bg-pink-300">
                <h2 className="title">
                    Sometimes a simple header is
                    <span className="fancy">worse</span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Header;
```